# Try catch block doesn't hit during Task Sequence

Tags: powershell, sccm

I have a peculiar situation where the try catch block doesn't hit in the script I have made.

```
Start-Transcript -Path C:\Trans.txt -Force -IncludeInvocationHeader
try
{
    $CDBJson = Get-Content -Path "C:\_SMSTaskSequence\CDB\CDB_Values.json1" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction Stop
    
    #Rename-Computer -NewName $CDBJson.DeviceName -Force
    
    $TSEnv = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment -ErrorAction Stop
    $TSEnv.Value("OSDComputerName") = $CDBJson.DeviceName
    
    Set-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Computername\Computername" -name "Computername" -value $CDBJson.DeviceName -ErrorAction Stop
    Set-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Computername\ActiveComputername" -name "Computername" -value $CDBJson.DeviceName -ErrorAction Stop
    Set-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" -name "Hostname" -value $CDBJson.DeviceName -ErrorAction Stop
    Set-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" -name "NV Hostname" -value $CDBJson.DeviceName -ErrorAction Stop

    $exitCode = 0
}
catch
{
    $exitCode = 1
}

Write-output $exitCode

exit $exitCode

Stop-Transcript
```

I made a typo in the `$CDBJson = Get-Content -Path "C:\_SMSTaskSequence\CDB\CDB_Values.json1" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction Stop` to force it to fail, but when I look in my Trans.txt, I can see that it fails to find the content, but doesn't actually trigger the catch block.

Funnily enough, if I press F8 during the Task Sequence to open the CMD and run the script manually from there, it does hit the catch block and does what I expect it to do.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here, so any advise is much appreciated

Comment: Try putting the `-ea stop` on the `Get-Content` instead of the `ConvertFrom-JSON`?

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I am just wondering why it was still working when running the script manually through CMD?

Comment: The environment might have `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` set when you run the script manually. I'd recommend that you set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the beginning of your script, which enables you to remove all of the `-ErrorAction Stop` arguments.

Comment: Ahhh, I was not aware of this! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @zett42 - That'll work, but I would consider it a "less than best" practice, as it makes it less immediately obvious that the author is specifically looking to trap the error from the specific cmdlet. As an example, `Test-Path` can return either `$true` or `$false`; you may want to address a nonexistent path using `if(){}` rather than `try{}catch{}`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin In OPs case it looks like as if they want to treat _all_ errors as critical errors by default. In this case adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to each cmdlet call would seem too verbose and error-prone to me. At my workplace we have a policy to put `$ErrorAction = 'Stop'` as the first line in _all_ scripts and knowing this, it is obvious to everyone that errors are handled via exceptions by default. When the default error handling mode is not suitable, we add e. g. `-ErrorAction Continue` on a case-by-case basis. This works very well for us.

Comment: @zett42 - That's more-or-less why I commented; it's not an outright BAD practice, but it makes some assumptions that I wouldn't automatically look for, and which might not apply. If it works for you, and/or for the querent here, by all means, go for it.